# Clear input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to clear ng-model inputs, but is not working, and i can't figure out why.

I have:

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.clear()"></button>
```

and in the clear action i have:

```
$scope.$event = null;
```

Should work, right?

If i do:

```
<button ng-click="$event = null"></button>
```

Will work, but i want avoid this in the HTML.

I already try to use angular.copy, and:

```
$scope.$event = {};
$scope.$event = '';
```

But doesn't work and is not giving me any erros message.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$event.title"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="$event.name"/>
<input type="number" ng-model="$event.age"/>
<input type="date" ng-model="$event.date"/>
```

Comment: How is your input field

Comment: See my update @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the click handler, `$event` refers to the event object not your `event` object in the scope.

Use another name to refer your object. Note that property names starting with `$` is normally used by angularjs to refer to its properties, so best we don't use them.

Comment: That's why Angular docs recommend you **never** prefix your models, services, etc with a dollar sign

Comment: @AmandaFerrari instead of `$event` as the object key, just use `event` or something like that